# Solve the equation: $ 3(\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x) + 4(\sin^7 x + \cos^7 x) = 7(\sin^5 x + \cos^5 x) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Problem**

> Solve the equation in $[0, \pi]$
> $$
> 3(\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x) + 4(\sin^7 x + \cos^7 x) 
> = 7(\sin^5 x + \cos^5 x)
> $$

- This problem is from the algebra round of a local high school competition that has ended.

I have not been able to get very far for this question, I can only see that we might try to use sum of cubes to simplify the first term into $3(\sin x + \cos x)(1 - \cos x \cdot \sin x)$. Could I receive some help for this question? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> $$
> 3(\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x) + 4(\sin^7 x + \cos^7 x) 
> = 7(\sin^5 x + \cos^5 x).
> $$

$$\begin{align}
3(\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x)-3(\sin^5 x + \cos^5 x) 
&= 4(\sin^5 x + \cos^5 x)- 4(\sin^7 x + \cos^7 x) \\
\\
3(\sin^3 x \cos^2x+ \cos^3 x\sin^2x)&= 4(\sin^5 x \cos^2x+ \cos^5 x\sin^2x) \\
\\
3\sin^2 x\cos^2 x(\sin x + \cos x)&= 4\sin^2 x\cos^2 x(\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x)
\end{align}$$

so we get:

$$\sin x=0, ~~\cos x=0,~~\sin x + \cos x=0,~~3=4(\sin^2x+\cos^2x-\sin x \cos x)$$
which is equivalent to
$$\sin x=0, ~~\cos x=0,~~\sin x + \cos x=0,~~\sin(2x)=\frac{1}2$$

Solution:

$$\boxed{x=0,~~x=\frac{\pi}{12},~~x=\frac{\pi}2,~~ x=\frac{3\pi}4,~~x=\frac{5\pi}{12},~~ x=\pi}$$

Comment: Congratulations! I like your answer very much! (+1)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: It's also equivalent to $\sin2x\in\left\{-1,\,0,\,\frac12\right\}$. This may be why the problem specifies a range of width $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sin x=s$ and $\cos x=c$.

$$(3s^3-7s^5+4s^4)+(3c^3-7c^5+4c^7)=0$$
$$s^3(3-7s^2+4s^4)+c^3(3-7c^2+4c^4)=0$$
$$s^3(4c^4-c^2)+c^3(4s^4-s^2)=0$$
$$4s^3c^4+4c^3s^4-(s^3c^2+c^3s^2)=0$$
$$4s^3c^3(s+c)-s^2c^2(s+c)=0$$
$$s^2c^2(s+c)(4sc-1)=0$$
And we conclude as Mathfail did.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you use the linearization of the powers of the sine and cosine functions
$$4(\sin ^3(x)+\cos ^3(x))= 3 \sin (x)-\sin (3 x)+3 \cos (x)+\cos (3 x)$$
$$16(\sin ^5(x)+\cos ^5(x))= 10 \sin (x)-5 \sin (3 x)+\sin (5 x)+10 \cos (x)+5 \cos   (3 x)+\cos (5 x)$$
$$64(\sin ^7(x)+\cos ^7(x))=5 \sin (x)-21 \sin (3 x)+7 \sin (5 x)-\sin (7 x)+35\cos (x)\\
+21 \cos (3 x)+7 \cos (5 x)+\cos (7 x)$$

So
$$\text{rhs - lhs}=\frac{1}{4}\, \sin ^2(2 x) \,(\cos (3 x)-\sin (3 x))$$